# Python RapidTriage.py

Tags: python, converters

Trying to convert RapidTriage.py to python 3.4. I keep getting an error:

```
"File "RapidTriage.py" line 152. in (module) outputfile.write(p.stdout.read()) Type Error: must be str, not bytes"
```

Here is the code

```
for cmd in cmds:
  split_cmd=cmd.split("::")
  outputfile.write("\t"+split_cmd[0]+":\t")
  p = subprocess.Popen(split_cmd[1], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  outputfile.write(p.stdout.read())
outputfile.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `Popen.stdout` will read in bytes if the `universal_newlines=False` on the `Popen` call, which is the default. So all calls to `p.stdout.read()` will return bytes if the `universal_newlines` keyword argument on the `Popen` call is not set to `True`. Because the default is `False` you are reading bytes not a string, but if you set it to `True` then `p.stdout.read()` should return a `str` type rather than bytes.

So this should fix your issue,

```
p = subprocess.Popen(split_cmd[1], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
outputfile.write(p.stdout.read())
```

This will convert the newlines to `\n` while the data is in program memory, but the `write` method will convert them back to the platform specific form when you output.

Alternatively you could just write the data as binary by opening `outputfile` as binary.

```
outputfile = open(file, 'wb')
```

Then you can write your code as follows.

```
for cmd in cmds:
  split_cmd=cmd.split("::")
  outputfile.write(('\t{0}:\t'.format(split_cmd[0])).encode(<optional encoding>))
  p = subprocess.Popen(split_cmd[1], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  outputfile.write(p.stdout.read())
outputfile.write("\n".encode(<optional encoding>))
```

Answer (score 0):

`p.stdout.read()` is of type bytes. You probably opened `outputfile` as `open(<filename>,"w")`. changing that to write bytes should fix this

```
ooutputfile = open(<filename>,"wb")
```

Or you can convert bytes to string while writing data into the file